# Android EditText Conversion to int

Tags: android, android-edittext, int

I'm trying to develop an Android app that is a timer. The user enters the amount of minutes and hours into the two EditTexts and using an intent, it puts the data into the stopwatch. Unfortunately, I keep on getting a NumberFormatException.

Here is my code.

Java

```
@Override
// Gets the view and initializes values for hours and mins
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
   View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_alarm, container, false);
   EditText hour = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.hours);
   EditText min = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.mins);
   alarm = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.start);
   hours = hour.getText().toString().trim();
   Log.d(TAG, "getting and turning into strings");
   mins = min.getText().toString().trim();
     alarm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
        checked.configureCheck(getData());

        }
    });
    return v;
}



private Bundle getData(){
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    try{
        int hour = Integer.parseInt(hours);
        int min = Integer.parseInt(mins);
        b.putInt("hours", hour);
        b.putInt("minutes", min);
    } catch(NumberFormatException e){
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return b;
}
```

Comment: `hours` and `min` will always be empty, or contain whichever default value you may have set in the xml. Your "getting and turning into strings" happens immediately -- not after you click the button. Your logcat should have told you that. You might want to pick up a basic Java/programming tutorial which explains the concepts of variables. Understanding this is essential to your success as a programmer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the root problem here is that you get the text right after finding view (which is always be null), so the parsing always get Exception.

Solution:

```
// Declare the 2 EditText as class variable
EditText hour, min;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
  // ...
  hour = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.hours);
  min = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.mins);
  // ...
}

private Bundle getData(){
  Bundle b = new Bundle();
  try {
    int hour = Integer.parseInt(hour.getText().toString().trim());
    int min = Integer.parseInt(min.getText().toString().trim());
    b.putInt("hours", hour);
    b.putInt("minutes", min);
  } catch(NumberFormatException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return b;
}
```

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Convert your editText data into an integer or a float.

```
Int a = Integer.valueOf(edittext.getText().toString());
```

Via this way, you can convert your string values into an integer